# ¿Cómo obtener los nombres de instrumentos y pistas en un archivo MIDI en iOS?

Tags: ios, midi

Usando el código en [este repositorio](https://github.com/NormannEiland/MidiFilePlayer/blob/master/src/ios/MidiPlayer.m) pude reproducir un archivo MIDI con una fuente predeterminada SoundFont, el problema es que el código requiere que se le pase como parámetros los instrumentos que se deben usar con cada pista.

La información de que instrumento usa cada pista esta embebida en el archivo MIDI.

Lo que he probado hasta el momento es iterar en los eventos del archivo buscando por meta-data pero al aparecer AudioToolbox Framework omite esa información cuando esta procesando el archivo.

```
- (void)assignInstrumentsToTracks:(NSArray*)programs {
    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Set the AUSampler nodes to be used by each track
    //-------------------------------------------------
    MusicTrack tracks[[programs count]];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [programs count]; i++) {
        MusicTrack track;
        MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(ms, (unsigned int)i, &track);
        tracks[i] = track;

        MusicEventIterator iterator;
        NewMusicEventIterator(track, &iterator);

        Boolean hasNext = YES;
        MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
        MusicEventType eventType = 0;
        const void *eventData = NULL;
        UInt32 eventDataSize = 0;

        // Run the loop
        MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasNext);
        while (hasNext) {
            MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator,
                                           &timestamp,
                                           &eventType,
                                           &eventData,
                                           &eventDataSize);

            // Process each event here
            printf("Eent type %i\n", (unsigned int)eventType);
            if (eventType == kMusicEventType_Meta) {
                printf("Meta-event found! ");
                for (int j=0; j<eventDataSize; j++) {
                    printf("%x", ((char *)eventData)[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

            MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator);
            MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasNext);
        }
    }

    AUNode nodes[[programs count]];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [programs count]; i++) {
        AUNode node;
        AUGraphGetIndNode (self.processingGraph, (unsigned int)i, &node);
        nodes[i] = node;
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [programs count]; i++) {
        MusicTrackSetDestNode(tracks[i], nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe de que otra forma de puede hacer ésto?

Answer (score 1):

La estrategia de iterar los eventos de cada pista es correcta, pero las asignaciones de instrumentos (Program Change events) no son meta-eventos, sino eventos de canal. Es decir: tendrías que buscar por `eventType=kMusicEventType_MIDIChannelMessage`, y `status` con valores entre `0xC0` y `0xCF`. Puedes ver un ejemplo en la función `MacMIDIObject::analyzeTrack()` de esta aplicación en C++:
https://sourceforge.net/p/kmid2/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mac/macmidiobject.cpp#l727

Por otro lado, los nombres de pistas y los nombres de instrumento sí que son meta-eventos de texto. Propiedad `metaEventType` con valor `TrackName=3`, e `InstrumentName=4`. Pero esta información de texto es puramente informativa y no influye en el sonido.